# How do I run two different types of tests within the same build script in team build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have the following sequence of things to do in my team build script after the sources are compiled:

```
-) Sources compiled
-) Run BVT tests (all tests in dlls *.bvt.dll)
-) Set build quality to BVTs Passed (or Rejected, if tests fail)
-) Run Unit tests (all tests in dlls *.unittests.dll)
-) Set build quality to Unit Tests Passed (or Rejected, if tests fail)
```

Can I accomplish this using team build script for VS 2008? If so, how?

EDIT: I have found a way to edit the build quality. Now all I need is to figure out how to run my tests in two stages. Anyone out there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way to run accomplish is to write custom build tasks/workflow activities. Since there are no more alternatives presented, this is being marked as the answer. If there are other answers, they will be considered.